# @RepositoryRestResource(exported = false) causes 405 response codes for most API calls, 404 for GET

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data-rest

I'm trying to hide a specific endpoint while allowing others to be automatically generated. If an endpoint is TRULY hidden, ANY api calls to that endpoint whether they are GET, POST, PUT, DELETE or whatever technically SHOULD return a 404 status code, because it should not exist. I'm getting a 404 when I try to do a GET on the collection, but I get a 405 response code when I try to POST to the collection, or other any other method type. Same goes for the item specific endpoint (eg /collection/id). I get a 404 correctly for the GET but get a 405 for DELETE or PUT, which should return 404. This seems like a bug to me.

Comment: You could be right, although maybe the designers specifically want to imply the method was intentionally omitted rather than just forgotten. Anyway, you might get more traction filing a bug here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST/